# Adding image over parallax (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently learning to use bootstrap and got stuck in this. I have set a parallax image in bootstrap, however, I can't add content (let's say a card or image regardless of the image) without breaking it.

As long as I can add a div over the parallax I will be happy.

The code with a text as an example (the idea is to add an image or a row):

```
<div id="parallax-image">
  <section>
    <div class="parallax-one">
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Heading</h2>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parallax-image .parallax-one{
  padding-top: 200px; 
  padding-bottom: 200px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-image: url(img/paralax_1.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

There is nothing special other than a font family and align for .text. I also have a media query that changes the paddling to 100px in small screens

**Edit**
I noticed that I can do a negative margin based on the paddling.
I can get a similar effect to what I'm looking for when adding to .text:

```
margin-bottom: -200px; margin-top: -140px
```

However, I'm not sure if something like this would have negative effects.

Comment: you want to add a text over your parallax background...?

Comment: To be more exact, I wanted to add two images or arow over the parallax (but unlike a line of text, it expands and break if I try to add them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an image is working with the current code that you have.
Can you let us know if the below behaviour is not what you are expecting?

```css
#parallax-image .parallax-one{
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Best-Desktop-Background-1.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="parallax-image">
<section>
  <div class="parallax-one">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Heading</h2>    
    </div>
    <img src="http://cdn.apk-cloud.com/detail/screenshot/21TMCtcX5zkbnDViowtD6roqiEPWaitP46F8aDkvJxErPuirh_H6kCa-cJbZmCpsrQ=h300.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="http://cdn.apk-cloud.com/detail/screenshot/21TMCtcX5zkbnDViowtD6roqiEPWaitP46F8aDkvJxErPuirh_H6kCa-cJbZmCpsrQ=h300.png" alt="image" />
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't use the available space, and in the case of your image, it expands the height from 446px to 746px

Comment: The extra height was added by the padding and the image which didn't have an explicit height set. If the size of the image is less than the div with the parallax effect, you wouldn't see the increase in height. Do you want the image to be cut off if it goes over the height of the parent div? Note that you have not explicitly set the height of the parallax div. By default, this will be auto and will increase to accommodate its content.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, I only needed to add max-height to the parallax and then use a negative margin to countereffect the padding-top.

Comment: Yes. Also, now that you have set the max-height, if your content overflows, it will appear clipped because of the `overflow: hidden` set. FYI, in case this is not what you wanted.